# Maven: where to store examples source code?

Tags: maven

Currently I'm working on open source project.
There exists bunch of java classes which are simple examples.

How should I organize this project with maven. Should I provide some packaging for them ?

Comment: I think you should add more details about what you want to do/have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the examples in a separate project and add your main project as a dependency. Package them according to what kind of code they are. (e.g. if the samples build a webapp, make the packaging a war)